# How can I disable company-mode in a shell when it is remote?

Tags: shell, company-mode

I am using `(global-company-mode 1)` but using remote shell it is annoyingly slow.

How can I disable company mode when I open a shell buffer, but only if it's a remote shell?

The problem manifests when I SSH to a remote server using `C-x f /ssh:root@server.com:/` and then `M-x shell`.

Comment: This is somewhere between a statement and a description.  What's the question?  Also, please clarify the description "using remote shell" (especially "using" is unclear and "remote shell" is also a bit vague).

Comment: I use `find-file` and open `M-x shell` on that location

Comment: I believe I was able to parse out your actual question @phoxd, but in the future, please put a specific question in the body of your question rather than using the title to add the necessary details. A simple "How can I disable company-mode in a shell when it is remote?" would ensure your question is answered and people don't skip over it.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: If you think the question shouldn't be closed, because it's clear to you and it and answers will help others, please edit the question to make it clear. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know that a buffer represents a remote connection, you can use `file-remote-p`.

You can read about this function [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html)

For example, in a shell buffer, `(file-remote-p default-directory)` will allow you to differentiate between a local shell and a remote shell.

In order to toggle company-mode, you can call the `company-mode` function with a parameter of `-1` (negative one).

To perform actions only in a shell buffer, you can add a function hook to the `shell-mode-hook` list. You can read about what hooks are and how to use them [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html)

Putting it all together:

1. Write a function that disables company mode in the current buffer only when it is remote:

```lisp
(defun my-shell-mode-setup-function () 
  (when (and (fboundp 'company-mode)
             (file-remote-p default-directory))
    (company-mode -1)))
```

2. Add this function to your `shell-mode-hook`s

```lisp
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-setup-function)
```