# What is causing Emacs remote shell to be slow on completion?

Tags: tramp, shell, completion, performance, company

So basically I am doing the following:

- Opening a dired buffer with tramp on a remote.
- Opening a shell on the remote (`M-x shell`)

Then if I try for example to type any command such as `ls -la` the prompt will display `l` and then take something like 10 seconds to display the remaining input.

If I `C-g` when the prompt is stuck at `l` then the hang time will disappear, and the remaining input will be directly displayed.

I believe this could be a completion problem, for some reason from my config emacs would be searching for stuff on the remote. As another thread mentioned I tried disabling (global-projectile-mode). I also have company installed.

The hard thing for debugging is that no output is displayed in messages. Any ideas on what may be causing this hang time?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this does the trick (disabling company mode on remote shells):

[How can I disable company-mode in a shell when it is remote?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55028/how-can-i-disable-company-mode-in-a-shell-when-it-is-remote)

```
(defun my-shell-mode-setup-function () 
  (when (and (fboundp 'company-mode)
             (file-remote-p default-directory))
    (company-mode -1)))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-setup-function)
```